# Vectorizing for loop to update vector all at once

Tags: r, vectorization

How can vectorize this snippet of code to update `theta` all at once?

```
for (j in 1:length(theta)) {
  val = exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)) * y * random_data_vector[j]
  val = val / (1 + exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)))
  theta[j] = theta[j] - (alpha * val)
}
```

`theta` is a vector, `random_data_vector` is a vector, `y` is a number

```
> dput(head(theta))
c(0.772925310069695, 0.853900654707104, 0.291106897871941, 0.114210048923269, 
0.257764941081405, 0.0881731726694852)
> dput(head(random_data_vector))
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Not sure you can vectorize like this as iterations depend on previous ones. Are you okay using Rcpp? Please provide some sample data for ``random_data_vector``, ``theta``, ``alpha`` and ``y``.

Comment: @F.Privé can you dive into why I can't vectorize? Everything is a real number vector except for `y` and `alpha` which are real numbers as well. My code seems to work but I may be missing a use case

Comment: When you compute `sum(theta * random_data_vector)`, you use `theta` from previous iteration, which prevents you from simply vectorizing your code.

Comment: @F.Privé a bit confused. I only modify `theta` during the last line that r2evans suggested. Doesn't `theta` stay the same in the other lines?

Comment: @F.Privé, `theta` never references `[j-1]`, so the value of `theta` after this loop is the same as before, but it does not rely on (for instance) the value of `theta[j-1]`. But I see your point ...

Comment: Liondancer, I suggest you use `dput(head(...))` instead of just `head(...)`, it makes it much easier for us to use.

Comment: @r2evans DONE. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I see the problem ... `theta` is within the `sum`, so it is not vectorized at that point, changing based on the previous change to `theta`. @Liondancer, **this is why you need sample data and expected output**, analogous to why programmers often require unit-tests for code.

Comment: @Liondancer, can you confirm the intended behavior? Do you have "truth" values to know that your loop is correct? (I'm just asking in case ...) If you do and my answer is correct, then we're good, otherwise I suggest you "unaccept" my answer below and find/confirm validation data.

Comment: @r2evans I tested your answer with some very basic examples and they behaved the way I wanted them to. I dont have a source of truth but I think youre good! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `for` loop or indexing required, since math ops in R are vectorized by default, assuming all vectors are either the same length or of length 1. (For example, `1:10 + 1` is vectorized by default, no loops required.)

```
val = exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)) * y * random_data_vector
val = val / (1 + exp(y * sum(theta * random_data_vector)))
theta = theta - (alpha * val)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why there is no need for `for` loop here?

Comment: It is vectorized by default, assuming all variables here are either length 1 or the same length as the other non-length-1 variables. Similarly, `1:10 + 1` is vectorized by default, no need for a `for` loop.

Comment: Perfect. It is good to add it to your perfect answer since it will be very helpful.

Comment: Not sure you can vectorize like this as iterations depend on previous ones.

Comment: You may be right ... though it depends on the data. If @Liondancer provides samples, perhaps we can verify this problem.

Comment: Try with `random_data_vector <- rnorm(5); theta <- rep(0, 5); alpha <- 1; y <- 0.5`.

Comment: @r2evans provided some sample data. Let me know if I am missing anything else

Comment: @F.Privé, good check, thanks for the QA. I suppose Liondancer's `for` loop might not be correct implementation of the intended calculation if this code is confirmed to be correct. You are right that the two are not equivalent, more supporting the utility of (unit-)tests.

Comment: @r2evans I think OP's implementation may be correct. It looks like a coordinate descent.

Comment: Perhaps. If so, then (1) it cannot be done in parallel, one of is distinct disadvantages; (2) that process continues until it is no longer reduced, not a predefined number of iterations as done here; and (3) what is the random vector for? I do see the reference to a continually-differentiable `F(x)` in there. Huh.